# Java - Converting to BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

I build a program to find out the largest prime factor of 2^1000. It worked, and gave the right answers to my smaller test numbers, but then I realized that for my number I would have to use BigInteger. I've never used it before so I'm pretty sure I did something wrong. The BigInteger program doesn't give me back anything and doesn't finish running.

Here's the program, using primitive data types, that works:

```
public class PE3 { public static void main(String[] args) {
  int num = 13195; 

  //find factors of 'num'
  for (int i=(num); i>2; i--) {
    if ((num%i)==0)
      testPrime(num, i); 
  }
 }

  // find if factor is prime
  public static void testPrime(int num, int i){
    for (int j=2; j<i; j++) {
      if ((i%j)==0) 
        break; 
      if (j==(i-1))
        System.out.println(i); 
}
  }}
```

Here's (what I think is) the same program using BigInteger:

```
import java.math.BigInteger; 

public class PE3BI { public static void main(String[] args) {
  BigInteger num = new BigInteger("600851475143"); 
  BigInteger zero = new BigInteger("0"); 
  BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1"); 
  BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2"); 

  //find factors of 'num'
  for (BigInteger i = new BigInteger("600851475143"); i.compareTo(two)==1; i.subtract(one)) {
    if ((num.mod(i))==zero)
      testPrime(num, i, one, zero); 
  }
  }

  // find if factor is prime
  public static void testPrime (BigInteger num, BigInteger i, BigInteger one, BigInteger zero){
    for (BigInteger j = new BigInteger("2"); j.compareTo(i)==-1; j.subtract(one)) {
      if ((i.mod(j))==zero) 
        break; 
      if (j.compareTo(i.subtract(one))==0)
      {System.out.println(i); 
        System.exit(0); }
    }}}
```

Comment: Use `i.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)` instead of == 0. Also, BigIntegers are immutable, j.subtract does nothing if you do not assign the value to something: j = j.subtract(one).

Comment: Also you probably want to do `j.add(one)` instead of `.subtract()` in the `for` loop in `testPrime()`.

Comment: And  `BigInteger`s are immutable, the arithmetic methods return a new `BigInteger` of the result, they don't modify the original one.

Answer (score 1):

While, piotrek's answer will solve one of your problems, your program still won't work.

Need to do's:

1. Don't use `==` for comparisons. It doesn't work for non-primitives, such as `BigInteger`(piotrek)
2. `i.subtract(one)` as the last item in a loop does nothing. Use `i = i.subtract(one)` and the equivalent for `j`.

Would be good:

Although technically correct, `a.compare(b) == -1` and `a.compare(b) == +1` are typically not the best practice for code readability and it might not be the case that `compare` returns one of these three values in all situations, so don't get in the habit. Use `a.compare(b) < 0` and `a.compare(b) > 0` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do comparisons like `object == zero`. it works only for primitives. now, your numbers are objects so it checks if reference is the same. change it to compare or equals

Comment: What would I do for something like `num.mod(i))==zero`?

Comment: same answer. first you must compute your number. that `num.mod(i)`. later you have to compare it with `zero`. but not using `==` as it doesn't work for objects the way you expect. use equals or compare instead. this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to use a long instead of the BigInteger class?

I just made this using your code to check if a number is prime or not prime:

```
long num = 600851475143L; 

boolean prime = true;//Check this after for loop for prime.
for (long i=2; i<num; i++) {//Loops through all numbers between 2 and the number given to test.
    if ((num%i)==0){//This is true if number is not prime.
        prime = false;
        System.out.println("Not prime: " + i);
        break; 
    }
}
```